# Given a dictionary of recipes how can I sort the dictionary such that all ingredient keys appear before they are in recipe values

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

Given a dictionary of recipes `{item: [ingredient_1, ingredient_2], ...}` how can I sort the item keys efficiently such that we would never have `item_n` appear after another `item_(n-m)`, m > 1, that used `item_n` as an ingredient.

for example:

```
{"cake" : ["egg", "sugar", "flour"], "flour": ["wheat", "titanium_dioxide"]}
```

should be sorted to

```
{"flour": ["wheat", "titanium_dioxide"], "cake" : ["egg", "sugar", "flour"]}
```

Comment: I don't understand. Can you explain but with a real example data? I feel like maybe the missing link here is that an `item` could be an `ingredient` in another `item` recipe? And in that scenario you would want the `item` (A) that is an `ingredient` in another `item` (B) recipe to appear before B?

Comment: Added an example, there are also no edge cases where we might have circular dependencies.

Comment: https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/

Comment: I know that doesn't immediately sound relevant, but it's very similar to what you're doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this simple algorithm:

1. For each `ingredient` in an `item`, if the ingredient has it's own entry in the dictionary (as a separate `item_2`), define an edge where `ingredient` is the source and `item` is the destination. When you do that for all ingredients/items, you basically get a directed graph.
2. If the graph is cyclic, no such valid ordering exists.
3. If the graph is acyclic (that is, a [DAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph)), use [topological sort](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/topological-sorting/) to get a valid ordering of items that need to be completed first (as a pre-requisite to some following item).

Answer (score 1):

Initialize an empty result list.

Initialize an empty hash table (or map or whatever) and call it `references`.  Iterate through all the recipes, and every time you come across a recipe name or ingredient name, set `references[name] = 0`.

Iterate through all the recipes again.  Every time you come across an ingredient,  increment `references[ingredient]` in the hash table.

Now a loop.

```
If `references` is empty, you have completed successfully.
Create an empty string array called `zeroes`.  
For each key `k` in `references`:
    if `references[k] == 0`:
        Remove `references[k]`
        Append k to `zeroes`
If `zeroes` is empty, there is a cyclic dependency, so fail.
For each key `k` in `zeroes`:
    If there is a recipe for `k`:
        In the recipe for `k`, for each ingredient `i`:
            decrement `references[i]`
        Add the recipe for `k` to the result list.
Restart the loop
```

If the loop completes successfully, the sorted recipes will be in the result list.

Comment: Isn't this a complicated/extended way of doing a topological sort? Also, you haven't specified what your algorithm outputs as an answer.

Comment: Edited.  It is indeed a topological sort, but without any of the details left out.